# What points help identify a cubic and an exponential graph?

Tags: exponential-function, algebraic-curves, cubics

What are the different points on the graph we need to know which would help determine the equation of the curve. For example in a quadratic graph, we can determine the equation if we know either any three points, vertex and y intercept, two roots and a point, y intercept and two roots, etc. Similarly what are the various points on the graph which would help determine the graph for a cubic and exponential graph?

Answer (score 2):

Let's discuss the case of a cubic. A cubic equation has the form $f(x)=ax^3 + bx^2+cd + d$. To fully determine the function, you need four pieces of information that will allow you to calculate $a,b,c,d$.

The simplest example of "four pieces of information" is the values of $f$ at four points, say $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$. If we know that
$$
f(x_i) = y_i  \quad \text{for} \; i=1,2,3,4
$$
then we have four linear equations that we can solve to get $a,b,c,d$. This is related to something called Lagrange interpolation.

An especially easy case is where three of the values are zeros of $f$. If we have $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3)=0$, then we know that $f(x)=k(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ for some $k$. A fourth known value of $f$ will then allow you to calculate $k$.

Another common case is where we know the value and first derivative of $f$ at two points. This again gives us a system of four linear equations that we can solve to get $a,b,c,d$. This is related to so-called Hermite interpolation.

Another example: maybe you know the value of $f$ and its first, second, and third derivatives at some particular point. This lets you construct the Taylor series for $f$ at this point, and that Taylor series is actually identical to $f$ itself.

The four pieces of information can be a diverse mixture. For example, if you know that $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$, $f(1) = 2$, and $f''(2) = 3$, then we have
\begin{align}
f(0) = 0    &\;\Longrightarrow\; d=0 \\
f'(0) = 0   &\;\Longrightarrow\; c=0 \\
f(1) = 2    &\;\Longrightarrow\; a+b+c+d =2 \\
f''(2) = 3  &\;\Longrightarrow\; 12a+4b = 3
\end{align}
which, again, you can solve to get  $a,b,c,d$.

So, in short, you need 4 pieces of information, which are typically values of the function or its derivative(s).

Comment: If you don't know the degree of the polynomial, you can only see the graph, then finding the degree would be done by how many solutions you see on the graph?

Comment: I don't know any way to determine the degree of a polynomial by looking at its graph. Why don't you ask this as a question, and maybe someone will answer it.